# Good Video Editing Software?

Tags: graphics, video

Im looking at video software. Im not sure what else to do? I use to run Cyberlink but cant since Im running the latest version of Ubuntu. What are my options?

Answer (score 1):

I use OpenShot.  OpenShot is an open-source program that creates, modifies, and edits video files. This is the most stable and easy to use program on Linux.

To install, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:openshot.developers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install openshot openshot-doc
```

Comment: Its asking for my sudo password in termincal and I cant put it in

Comment: Why can't you?  What error message are you getting?

Comment: I wasnt getting an error message it wasnt letting me type nothing after the first command sudo add-apt-repository ppa:openshot.developers/ppa.    All it said was sudo Jeremiah PeachBuntu password: then it wouldnt let me type

Comment: You don't need to type a password after the first command.

Answer (score 0):

I use Kdenlive.

Type the following into a terminal:
`sudo apt-get install kdenlive`

It has numerous effect plugins (more than I can keep track of) plus transition plugins. Some of the effect plugins support keyframing.
It can also render to any libav (ffmpeg) supported format/container.

Comment: How do I get to Kdenlive??

Comment: Type the `sudo apt-get` line in my answer into a terminal.

Comment: I'm not sure how well that runs in unity or gnome based systems, though

Comment: KDE apps will work fine on non-KDE systems, so long as you have all of the dependencies installed (installing through apt-get will do that, and they don't depend on the KDE environment, just some core libs like Qt and some low-level KDE system libs). It may not look like the rest of the desktop, but users can configure this behavior using the Qt config tool (`sudo apt-get install qt4-qtconfig`)